# How to add external jar to Scala in Jupyter kernel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I would like to add the jar files from Stanford's CoreNLP into my Scala project. The part I'm struggling with in doing this in the context of a Scala kernel for Jupyter notebooks.

I'm using the Apachee Toree distribution for the kernel. There may be a simple one line command within-cell, but I can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this applies to `Stanford CoreNLP`, but in a past project that involves evaluation of using [IBM DSX](https://datascience.ibm.com/) on Jupytor Notebook, I read this [article](https://medium.com/@DustinVanStee/how-to-add-a-custom-library-to-a-jupyter-scala-notebook-in-ibm-data-science-experience-dsx-d85e97bc2e10) by Dustin V which consists of steps for adding jars.  My guess is that the within-cell command you're seeking might be something similar to the following:

```
%AddJar http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar -f
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that post. AddJar is actually only for a url link unfortunately.